# Modify the size of the input textbox widget for a raw_id_fields field

Tags: django-admin

I'm trying  to make the input textbox of a raw_id_fields wider than the default size  but without success.
Here is what I tried ('codarticolo' is the raw_id_fields) to no avail:

### admin.py

```
class MovimentomagInline(admin.TabularInline):
    codarticolo = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 80}))
    raw_id_fields = ['codarticolo',]
    fields = ('codarticolo', 'numconfezioni', 'numerounita','totalepezzi')
    model = Movimentomag
    extra=3


class MovimentomagOption(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('codarticolo', 'numconfezioni', 'numerounita','totalepezzi')
    fields = ('codarticolo', ('numconfezioni', 'numerounita','totalepezzi',))

class MovimentoOperazioneOption(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('segno', 'data_movimento', 'paziente','operatore')
    fields = (('segno','data_movimento'),('paziente','operatore'))
    inlines = [MovimentomagInline,]
    order_by = ['-data_movimento',]
```

What should I do?
Ciao
Vittorio

Answer (score 1):

Probably 5 years too late :(.

I was facing the same issue. The following should work.

```
attrs={'style': 'width: 80px'}
```

What it does  is to set the style property of the HTML *input* element.

Hope it helps.